# Searching an item with an for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to do a for loop which would search over every row in data frame, but just the 
first column checking the `tag ID`, and if its not it, then it should move to the next row and so on until it finds the value or get to the end of the data frame.
Then the row as a result should be printed.

The purpose is just checking how the for loop works and how "slow" it is ( I want it to compare to other way of searching). I am a bit inexperienced in R and programming general.

**Progress so far/my code**

Thus far I have done this code and the stopping point is how to make the function move to the other column and check it and move to the next.

```
SearchID = function(data,value) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(testdata)) {
    row <- testdata[i,1]
    if("row" == "value") return(row)
    #what now?
  }

}
```

This is an reproducible example:

```
ID=c("ID43","ID23","ID14","ID14")
y=c(23,45,66,76)
k=c("yes","no","yes","no")

testdata= data.frame(ID,y,k)
```

If I give the `ID14` as `value`, it should return the whole row with the `ID14`:

```
    ID   y   k
 4  ID14 76  no
```

Comment: Why not just `testdata[testdata$ID == "ID14", ]`

Comment: @AnandaMahto

I know about the "short cut", but I as I am trying to learn R, and I have never learned any other programming language, I would like to see that other solution.

Comment: Also, don't quote "row" and "value" when you are doing your comparison. And return the relevant row (`testdata[i, ]`) instead of the value of `row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, first you create an object `d1` to hold the rows that match the `value` with the `ID` column.  We are looping through each row of the `data` with the `for` loop and check the condition.  If it matches, then use `rbind` to bind that row with the created object.  You can also initialize `d1` as `d1 <- data.frame()`.

```
SearchID <- function(data,value) {
        d1 <- c()
       for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
        row <- data[i,1]
         if(row==value){
        d1 <- rbind(d1,data[i,])
          }
       }
    d1
  }

 SearchID(testdata, 'ID14')
 #   ID  y   k
 #3 ID14 66 yes
 #4 ID14 76  no

 SearchID(testdata, 'ID43')
 #  ID  y   k
 #1 ID43 23 yes

  SearchID(testdata, "ID86")
  #NULL
```

Comment: Can I ask you to explain a bit? Row by row?

If I understand correctly:
1. you create an empty vector
2. search with for loop
3. if its the right value you `rbind` the data to the vector
4. return the value d1.

Did I get that rigt?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what assumptions about R knowledge can be made in trying to answer this question. For instance, if we could assume that we know how to extract rows based on a vector of row indices, the following would seem more natural to me than binding the rows one-by-one:

```
SearchID = function(data,value) {
  getme <- numeric()                       # Initialize empty vector
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {                 # Start the loop
    row <- data[i, 1]                      # Capture the relevant value
                                           # Compare, and If there's a match,
    if (row == value) getme <- c(getme, i) # add loop index to "getme" vector
  }
  if (length(getme) == 0) NULL             # If the vector is still empty, NULL
  else data[getme, ]                       # else return the relevant rows
} 

SearchID(testdata, "ID14")
#     ID  y   k
# 3 ID14 66 yes
# 4 ID14 76  no
```

---

At the very least, this answer should give you something else to benchmark against :-)